# Android - facebook UnsupportedOperationException when tryint to post

Tags: android, facebook, session, fragment, unsupportedoperation

Here is my code

```
package mypackage.fragments;

public class TeachersDetailedFragment extends Fragment implements MyInterface,
        OnClickListener {

private Session.StatusCallback callback;
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

private Button shareButton;
private LoginButton lb;

private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";

public TeachersDetailedFragment() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    Log.i("Tag:", getTag());

    ...

    callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRetainInstance(true);

    ...

    lb = (LoginButton) parentView.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    lb.setFragment(this);

    shareButton = (Button) parentView.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
    shareButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            publishStory(null, pendingPublishReauthorization);
        }
    });

    ...

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        pendingPublishReauthorization = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(
                PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, false);
    }

    return parentView;
}


private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
        Exception exception) {

    if (state.isOpened()) {
        shareButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // lb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (pendingPublishReauthorization
                && state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
            publishStory(null, pendingPublishReauthorization);
        }

        Log.i("facebook", "Logged in...");
        // TODO hide logout button
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        shareButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.i("facebook", "Logged out...");
    }
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
    uiHelper.onResume();

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e("result meghívva", "meghívva ez a fos");
    // Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(),
    // requestCode,
    // resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
    MainActivity.fragmentList.remove(getTag().toString());
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, pendingPublishReauthorization);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void publishStory(List<String> PERMISSIONS,
        boolean pendingPublishReauthorization) {
    final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null) {

        // Check for publish permissions
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        try {
            if (!isSubsetOf(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"), permissions)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                        getActivity(), Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest); //ERROR HERE - line //607
                return;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sajnos nem sikerült megosztani, próbáljon újra bejelentkezni",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // session.close();
        }

        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        String[] images = feedItem.getImages();
        postParams.putString("name", feedItem.getFirstname() + " "
                + feedItem.getLastname() + " " + feedItem.getName());
        postParams.putString("caption", "test");
        postParams.putString("description", "test");
        postParams.putString("link", feedItem.getUrl());
        postParams.putString("picture", (Globals.BASE_URL + images[0]));

        Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(com.facebook.Response response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject()
                            .getInnerJSONObject(); //ERROR HERE - LINE 633
                    String postId = null;
                    postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.i("exception", "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
                }
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (error != null) {
                    Log.e("face megosztás hiba", error.getErrorMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Sajnos nem sikerült megosztani",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    session.close();
                } else {
                    Log.i("facebook", "sikeres post");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Sikeresen megosztva!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    // session.close();
                }
            }

        };

        Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams,
                HttpMethod.POST, callback);

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();

    }

}

private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset,
        Collection<String> superset) {
    for (String string : subset) {
        if (!superset.contains(string)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

The login is succesfull, and after that, i am trying to post to facebook, but my app crasches, saying the following in the logcat:

```
01-06 19:59:06.966: W/System.err(13701): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an 

attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.
01-06 19:59:06.967: W/System.err(13701):    at com.facebook.Session.requestNewPermissions(Session.java:1248)
01-06 19:59:06.967: W/System.err(13701):    at com.facebook.Session.requestNewPublishPermissions(Session.java:595)
01-06 19:59:06.967: W/System.err(13701):    at hu.karathb.netcar.fragments.TeachersDetailedFragment.publishStory(TeachersDetailedFragment.java:607)
01-06 19:59:06.967: W/System.err(13701):    at hu.karathb.netcar.fragments.TeachersDetailedFragment.access$2(TeachersDetailedFragment.java:594)
01-06 19:59:06.967: W/System.err(13701):    at hu.karathb.netcar.fragments.TeachersDetailedFragment$2.onClick(TeachersDetailedFragment.java:120)
01-06 19:59:06.967: W/System.err(13701):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
01-06 19:59:06.967: W/System.err(13701):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
01-06 19:59:06.967: W/System.err(13701):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-06 19:59:06.967: W/System.err(13701):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-06 19:59:06.967: W/System.err(13701):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-06 19:59:06.967: W/System.err(13701):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
01-06 19:59:06.967: W/System.err(13701):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-06 19:59:06.967: W/System.err(13701):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-06 19:59:06.968: W/System.err(13701):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
01-06 19:59:06.968: W/System.err(13701):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
01-06 19:59:07.212: D/AndroidRuntime(13701): Shutting down VM
01-06 19:59:07.214: E/AndroidRuntime(13701): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 19:59:07.214: E/AndroidRuntime(13701): Process: hu.karathb.netcar, PID: 13701
01-06 19:59:07.214: E/AndroidRuntime(13701): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'org.json.JSONObject com.facebook.model.GraphObject.getInnerJSONObject()' on a null object reference
01-06 19:59:07.214: E/AndroidRuntime(13701):    at hu.karathb.netcar.fragments.TeachersDetailedFragment$8.onCompleted(TeachersDetailedFragment.java:633)
01-06 19:59:07.214: E/AndroidRuntime(13701):    at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1666)
01-06 19:59:07.214: E/AndroidRuntime(13701):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-06 19:59:07.214: E/AndroidRuntime(13701):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-06 19:59:07.214: E/AndroidRuntime(13701):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-06 19:59:07.214: E/AndroidRuntime(13701):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
01-06 19:59:07.214: E/AndroidRuntime(13701):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-06 19:59:07.214: E/AndroidRuntime(13701):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-06 19:59:07.214: E/AndroidRuntime(13701):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
01-06 19:59:07.214: E/AndroidRuntime(13701):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

What can be the problem? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think your Request is not finished processing or you haven't finished with the connection correctly.  The error says that it spawns from facebook telling you you cannot request new permissions in a session that is busy.

Comment: and how can i solve it?

Comment: You can probably close the session and open a new one to prevent that conflict.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here.

First is your app requesting publish permissions while there's still a pending operation (did you post your whole Fragment? It seems that there's a TeachersDetailedFragment.access class/method that's not here). I think this is because you're first opening a session, but then immediately requesting publish permissions before the first open finishes. Remember that session opens (and new permissions requests) are asynchronous, so you must wait for the onSessionStateChange methods before requesting new permissions.

Secondly is your NPE, which is actually what's crashing your app. This is purely because you don't have a result (since you haven't gotten the permissions yet), so the graphResponse.getGraphObject() is null, and if you try to call getInnerJSONObject on it, it will throw an NPE. This is not related to the SDK at all, but you should always do a null check (or check for errors from the graphResponse first).

Comment: All the relevant code is here from the fragment, i don't have a classname.access method. I got the code for posting from the official "tutorial", from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share?locale=hu_HU - sharing links via APIs; and the login part from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.2?locale=hu_HU - and that is why i don't understand, why it is not working

Comment: I noticed that in your newPermissionsRequest you're passing in getActivity(), try passing in "this" instead.

Comment: I will try, but I don't think it will work, since "this" is a fragment.

Comment: That's the whole point. I know "this" is a fragment, which is why you should pass in "this". Otherwise the onActivityResult will be called on your parent Activity, which I'm guessing is not calling uiHelper.onActivityResult.

Comment: I am not home, so i could not try it yet, but i thought that lb.setFragment(this) takes care of calling onActivityResult in the fragment. I will write updates tomorrow!

Comment: That's only for the login button, when you request new permissions, that doesn't go through the login button, but through the session directly.

Comment: There were several problems.1st: You were right, fragment had to be passed to newPermissionsRequest. Thanks for it! 2nd: "pendingPublishReauthorization" was never set to true, since it was passed - but this is not really a problem, just prevents the publish() funcion to be called after the user accepts permissions. 3rd: if you want to use publish permission, you have to send your app for review to facebook... so I went for another, much simple and easier solution, i will write it soon